# JSON Schema validation for different property values

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am attempting to validate the following JSON file:

```
{
"Transaction": {
    "Header": {
        "Workflow": "Rejection",
        "Job-Offer": {
            "Offer-Status": "New",
            "Datetime-Offered": "2017-12-15T16:00:00",
            "Accepted": "YES",
            "Datetime-Accepted": "2017-12-15T16:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

}

against the following schema:

```
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
"title": "Schema",
"description": "Schema",
"$ref": "#/defs/Schema",
"defs": {
    "Schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "Transaction": {
                "$ref": "#/defs/Transaction"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Transaction"
        ],
        "title": "Schema"
    },
    "Transaction": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "Transaction-Header": {
                "$ref": "#/defs/Transaction-Header"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Transaction-Header"
        ],
        "title": "Transaction"
    },
    "Transaction-Header": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "Workflow": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "Offer",
                    "Transfer",
                    "Acceptance",
                    "Rejection",
                    "Cancellation",
                    "Update"
                ]
            },
            "Job-Offer": {
                "$ref": "#/defs/JobOffer"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Workflow"
        ],
        "title": "Transaction-Header"
    },
    "JobOffer": {
        "description": "Job Offer.",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": true,
        "properties": {
            "Offer-Status": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "New",
                    ""
                ]
            },
            "Datetime-Offered": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "Accepted": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    ""
                ]
            },
            "Datetime-Accepted": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "Reason-Rejected": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 0,
                "maxLength": 30
            },
            "Offer-Cancelled": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "YES",
                    "NO",
                    ""
                ]
            },
            "Datetime-Cancelled": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            }
        },
        "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/defs/JOBACCEPT" },
            { "$ref": "#/defs/JOBREJECT" }
        ],
        "required": [
            "Offer-Status"
        ],
        "title": "JobOffer"
    },
    "JOBACCEPT": {
        "properties": {
            "Workflow": { "enum": [ "Acceptance" ] }
        },
        "required": [ 
            "Accepted",
            "Datetime-Accepted" 
        ],
    },
    "JOBREJECT": {
        "properties": {
            "Workflow": { "enum": [ "Rejection" ] }
        },
        "required": [ 
            "Reason-Rejected" 
        ],
    }
}
```

}

What I am after is:

If the Workflow of "Acceptance" is selected, the fields under JOBACCEPT are required.
If the Workflow of "Rejection" is selected, the fields under JOBREJECT are required.

I have tried many different combinations of oneOf, allOf, anyOf, if-then-else but nothing seems to work correctly.

Anyone have any ideas what needs to be done?

Re-worked json inline:

```
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
"$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "Transaction": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "Transaction-Header": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Workflow": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "Offer",
              "Transfer",
              "Acceptance",
              "Rejection",
              "Cancellation",
              "Update"
            ]
          },
          "Job-Offer": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Offer-Status": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "New",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "Datetime-Offered": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
              },
              "Accepted": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "YES",
                  "NO",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "Datetime-Accepted": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
              },
              "Reason-Rejected": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 0,
                "maxLength": 30
              },
              "Offer-Cancelled": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "YES",
                  "NO",
                  ""
                ]
              },
              "Datetime-Cancelled": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "Offer-Status"
            ]
          },
          "readOnly": true
        },
        "required": [
          "Workflow"
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "Transaction-Header"
    ]
  }
},
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "Transaction": {
          "properties": {
            "Transaction-Header": {
              "properties": {
                "Workflow": {
                  "enum": [
                    "Acceptance"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "Workflow"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "Transaction": {
          "properties": {
            "Transaction-Header": {
              "properties": {
                "Job-Offer": {
                  "properties": {},
                  "required": [
                      "Accepted",
                      "Datetime-Accepted"
                    ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
"required": [
  "Transaction"
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea. The problem is where you've placed the `allOf` with your conditionals. You have it in the "JobOffer" schema, but are trying to set constraints on the "Workflow" property which is in the "Transaction-Header" schema. There is no way to reference a property that is higher up in the JSON tree structure, so you need to move the `allOf` up into the "Transaction-Header" schema so you can set constraints on the "Workflow" property.

Now that it's in the right place, the best way to express your conditional constraints is with `if`/`then`. The context of the `if`/`then` is now the the "Transaction-Header" schema, so the `then` schemas needs to not just say what properties are required, they need to declare that those properties are in the "Job-Offer" object.

```json
{
  ...

  "defs": {
    ...

    "Transaction-Header": {
      ...

      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/defs/JOBACCEPT" },
        { "$ref": "#/defs/JOBREJECT" }
      ]
    },

    "JOBACCEPT": {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Workflow": { "enum": ["Acceptance"] }
        },
        "required": ["Workflow"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "Job-Offer": {
            "required": ["Accepted", "Datetime-Accepted"]
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "JOBREJECT": { ... Similar to JOBACCEPT ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: And boom, yes that has indeed fixed it (in the abstracted method - which is fine for my usage).  You're a star Jason, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're abstracting everything away into definitions *, so it's tricky to express conditionals that reference things multiple layers deep. If you inline all the definitions, it gets a little easier to see what needs to be done.

The `if`/`then` keywords need to be at the level of 'Transaction'. In pseudocode:

"if the property 'Header' exists (i.e. `required`) and its value is ... (`const`), then require property ... with value (type=object, required properties=[...], property definitions=...)", and so on.

* by the way, in version 2020-12 the definitions keyword is `$defs` -- it may work the way you have it, but implementations will be unable to validate the schemas undef `defs` as they won't recognize them there, so some errors can slip through and be harder to find.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ether . Ironically, I had all this inline but read another post which had it separated into refs. Re-worked back inline and I have updated the original question with the look of it. I am still not getting the results I am after. Have I got the if in the correct place?

Comment: You just need to wrap those `if`/`then` pairs into an `allOf`, as you can't repeat property names in json. Also, your `then` clauses seem to be assuming that the properties are at the top level, but they're actually nested a few layers deep? so you'll need to repeat the `"properties": { ...: { "required": [..] } }` bits there (the error message should make that clear).

Comment: This is quite confusing @Ether.  I have amended the re-worked version based on your last comments but still no joy and no error either, just message `No errors found. JSON validates against the schema`

Comment: Is it "Transaction-Header", or "Header"?

Comment: It is actually Transaction-Header but I had created a separate "shortened" script.  All is OK now though as I have managed to get it to work in the abstracted format.  I could just adopt that to the inline one if need be.  Thanks for the help though.